# TCP sockets: How much incoming data is buffered before calling accept?

Tags: sockets, networking, kernel, tcp

Consider a server process that is listening on a port for incoming TCP connections.

The kernel keeps a "pending connections queue" for incoming TCP connections which have not yet been accepted by the server process.
At this pending state, I expect the full TCP handshake to be already finished (syn, syn ack, ack)?

However only when the server process calls the "accept" system call, one of the pending connections gets actually established and popped from the queue, allowing to send  and receive data to/from the server process.

I have two concrete questions.

- Does the kernel accept incoming payload data before the server process has "accepted" a connection? This incoming data must be buffered in a "socket receive buffer", waiting for the server process to accept the connection and eventually read the data.

  If the answer is no, how does the kernel reject payload data while keeping the connection alive? By setting the TCP receive window size to zero?

  If the answer is yes, how does the kernel prevent an excessive usage of RAM caused by bloating socket receive buffers? Of course there must be some reasonable receive buffer limit configured.
- How long does the kernel keep pending connections alive which have not yet been accepted by the server process? Does the kernel send keep-alive messages for pending TCP connections?

Comment: syn-ack is not sent until the connection has been accepted so there will be no data.

Comment: Can you confirm this with some documentation? This implies that I always have to use at least two threads when implementing a server with a fast syn-ack-response-time, even if I use only one thread for processing requests

Comment: I might write a small c program to test the syn-ack timing, using Wireshark for capturing the handshake. But I am also asking about kernel internals.

Comment: "_Can you confirm this with some documentation?_" See _[RFC 793, Tansmission Control Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793)_, the definition of TCP.

Comment: Actually I think that this question is about an OS implementation detail rather than about the TCP protocol itself. Therefore the TCP RFC does not include such details about the socket programming interface.

Comment: After some research I think I was wrong. Take a look at http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html and https://blog.cloudflare.com/syn-packet-handling-in-the-wild/